# After the death of the pharaoh

Tags: prophet-musa

I have reasearched  but i couldnt find where musa a.s went after the death of the pharaoh. 
Does anyone know where musa a.s went after the death of the pharaoh? which place did he went?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. This question seem only to tangent the topic of the site IMO a better fit would be [history stack exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Medi1Saif: Isn't inquiring about the Prophets at different stages in their life a part of exploring Islam?

Comment: @FahadUddin I don't disagree, but that is subjective. Knowing where Musa was afterwards doesn't have any impact on our faith and won't help us knowing significantly more about Islam than a few facts that are rather irrelevant to the teaching of this religion which is in the focus of this site. If the question was what do Muslim sources tell us about it I wouldn't have posted that comment at all.

Answer (score 1):

You will find a more detailed answer in the Jewish traditions to this question tough some pointers are available in Islam too.

After the incident of the spitting the Red Sea and the death of Pharoah and his army,  the Israelites continued their journey to the Promised Land, they came upon a people who were worshiping idols.

The Israelites requested to have an idol to worship, but Moses refused and stated that the polytheists would be destroyed by God. [They were granted manna and quail as sustenance from God](https://quran.com/2/57), but [the Israelites asked Moses to pray to God for the earth to grow lentils, onions, herbs and cucumbers for their sustenance](https://quran.com/2/61).

When they stopped in their travel to a promised land due to their lack of water, [Moses was commanded by God to strike a stone, and upon its impact twelve springs came forth, each for a specific tribe of the Israelites](https://quran.com/2/60).

After this, from other sources, we also find mention of:

- Revelation of the Torah
- The incident of the Israelites and the cow
- Meeting of Musa and Khidr
- The incident of Musa and the Angel of death
- Death of Musa
- Meeting of Musa and Adam